# When I load from a .nib do I still need to create a view to assign to View?

Tags: monomac

Assuming that I call

```
  protected MyViewController(string nibName, NSBundle bundle)  :
     base(nibName, bundle) { }
```

do I still need to

```
public override void LoadView
{
  View = new MyView(...);
  base.LoadView()
}
```

It seems that calling the nib should just make the View. Am I misunderstanding how nibs work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your understanding is correct.

You use `LoadView` to instantiate the view if you are *not* using a .xib (i.e. you are creating the programatically).

If you are using a .xib, don't override `LoadView`

Comment: Actually, you can override LoadView() and call base.LoadView(). Turns out that there was an issue in my .nib where there was no "view" to connect.